# Determine if a stationary point of a 3 variable scalar field is a saddle point given its hessian matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices

The Hessian matrix a a stationary point p is :
H(p) =$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -3 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & -4 \\
    0 & -4 & 8 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
How to determine if it is a saddle point or not. Shall I diagonalize it or is there a faster way to see it ?

Comment: $2\times8-4\times4 = 0$, so this matrix is singular. It has eigenvalues $-3$, $0$, and $2+8=10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let refer to [Sylvester criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) and observe that

- $\det(-3)=-3<0$
- $\det \left(\begin{smallmatrix}-3&0\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)=-6<0$
- $\det(A)=0$

then the signature is $(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q$ be the quadratic form of $H(p)$. Then it is easy to see that

$Q(1,1,0)>0$ and $Q(0,0,-1) <0$. Hence $H(p)$ is indefinite.